# How to center text blocks in memoir class under twoside/default option?

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm using `memoir` class to write a book; the output is fine for the purpose of printing -- the text on odd pages being placed slightly to the left, and the text of the even pages being placed slightly to the right.

However, now I want each page to have a central text alignment, i.e., the text on both the odd and the even page numbers to be aligned. Could one achieve this with memoir?

I understand that `letter` or `article` instead of `memoir` do the trick, but then the paragraphs change, etc.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx!

Comment: Note that 'centered text' usually refers to a form of symmetrical text alignment with uneven margins on both sides, not a single-sided page layout.

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed in section **2.8 Side margins** of the [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/memoir):

> Some documents are designed to have, say, a very wide righthand margin in which to
>   put illustrations; this leads to needing the spine margin on verso pages to be much larger
>   than the spine margin on recto pages. This can be done with the `oneside` option. However,
>   different headers and footers are required for the recto and verso pages, which can only be done with the `twoside` option. The way to get the desired effects is like this (`twoside` is the default class option):
>
> ```
> \documentclass{memoir}
> %%% set up the recto page layout
> \checkandfixthelayout% or perhaps \checkandfixthelayout[lines]
> \setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}% after \checkandfix...
> ...
> ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%%% set up the recto page layout
\checkandfixthelayout% or perhaps \checkandfixthelayout[lines]
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}% after \checkandfix...

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```